# Disable ATI Radeon graphics card and use intel graphics (switcheroo unavailable)

Tags: 12.04, ati, switchable-graphics

So I have a HP Envy with ATI Radeon 5450 + intel switchable graphics. I think (though I'm not sure) that the Radeon is running right now on Ubuntu 12.04 (because my laptop is making too much noise when I'm doing something non gpu intensive like word processing, or web browsing).

So what I want to do is disable the ATI Radeon and use the Intel instead. I looked around and it seems all the solutions use switcheroo, but I dont have it on my computer! I think this happened because I tried installing the proprietary driver (fglrx).

Any and all help is 200% appreciated, thank you

Comment: bump fifteenchar

Answer (score -1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

have you tried that one?

Josvanr